# How can i get the parameters sent in AnjLab SqlProfiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

When i'm doing some sort of query to the db through a site, SQL Server Profiler throws me this TextData:

```
exec sp_executesql N' SELECT (...)  FROM (...) IDExample = @IDExample ORDER BY (...) ',
N'@IDExample int', @IDExample = 5
```

When i'm trying to do the same exact thing with AnjLab Sql Profiler (with which I am more comfortable working), i get the same thing, but without the parameters:

```
exec sp_executesql N' SELECT (...)  FROM (...) IDExample = @IDExample ORDER BY (...) '
```

There is some sort of config that i can set to get the parameters in AnjLab SQL Profiler?

Comment: This would be better asked on AnjLab's support forums, if they exist.  It isn't really a programming question.

Comment: You are right Tab, it isn't a programming question, I got carried away by other questions of the same nature that I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible to get parameters in AnjLab SQL Profiler without changing codebase.